# removeProp for ID property

Tags: jquery, properties

With the [following setup](http://jsfiddle.net/veGCe/):

```
<div id="foo"/>​
```

JavaScript (jQuery 1.8.0):

```
$('#foo').removeProp('id').prop('id', 'bar');

alert($('#bar').length);
alert($('#foo').length);
alert($('#undefined').length);​
```

Note that the elements ID has not been updated to `bar` as I expected it to be (only the final alert yields `1`) (Chrome 21)

This seems to be related to my use of `removeProp('id')`; which, whilst redundant in this example (when I can just set the `id` to `bar` directly), is required in my *final* code.

Now I'm curious as to what the **correct** way is to remove an ID in JavaScript; should I have used `removeAttr()`? Is this a bug in jQuery? Is it legal to remove an ID once setting it?

Comment: from jQuery docs _The `.removeProp()` method removes properties set by the `.prop()` method.
With some built-in properties of a DOM element or window object, browsers **may generate an error** if an attempt is made to remove the property. jQuery first assigns the value **undefined** to the property and ignores any error the browser generates. In general, it is only necessary to remove custom properties that have been set on an object, and not built-in (native) properties._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things to note, here, the first is that the `id` is an attribute, not a property, so `attr()`/`removeAttr()` should be used instead.

The second is the the API for `removeProp()` explicitly note that you should not:

> ...use this method to remove native properties such as `checked`, `disabled`, or `selected`. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use `.prop()` to set these properties to `false` instead.

Also, rather than unsetting, and then setting, why not simply change it with `attr()`:

```
$(elem).attr('id', 'newValue');
```

Comment: Humm, I only briefly touched upon it in my question; I'm not setting the `id` again immediately. I'm basically cloning a template (which has an ID), and so need to remove the ID to add it to the DOM (to keep the ID unique), then *some time later* I'm adding this ID again.

Comment: ... so in this case do you recommend `prop('id', false)` or `removeAttr('id')`? I guess my understanding of attributes/ properties isn't what I thought it was... doesn't all property changes get reflected in the attribute in the most part (excluding things like `checked` etc?).

Comment: I'd honestly just set the `id` to an empty string or use `removeAttr('id')` (probably the latter).

Comment: Eugh, and so lastly (sorry, I'm struggling to grasp this attribute/ property thing), I should be **setting** an ID with `prop()` or `attr()`? (You said `id` is an attribute, but I also see it listed under [the MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.id) as a property...)

Comment: My broad, though unschooled, assumption when dealing with jQuery is that a property is something that's essentially Boolean (it's there, or it's not, but doesn't require a quoted value (`checked` for example *can* be written as `checked="checked"`, but is valid as simply `checked` within the element's opening tag). Whereas an `id` *requires* a value to be set, so `id`, `class`, `height`, `src`...So, under this understanding, *set* an `id` with `attr()`. =)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you trying.. but to set the ID you can simply set like below,

```
$('#foo')[0].id = 'bar'
```

However jQuery does mention below,

> The `.removeProp()` method removes properties set by the `.prop()` method.
>
> With some built-in properties of a DOM element or window object, browsers may generate an error if an attempt is made to remove the property. jQuery first assigns the value **undefined** to the property and ignores any error the browser generates. In general, it is only necessary to remove custom properties that have been set on an object, and not built-in (native) properties.
>
> **Note:** Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

Comment: I only briefly touched upon it in my question; I'm not setting the `id` again immediately. I'm basically cloning a template (which has an ID), and so need to remove the ID to add it to the DOM (to keep the ID unique), then *some time later* I'm adding this ID again. I'm not seeing any errors in my browser console though, so is jQuery on about an unthrown error, or do they catch it for me so I can't detect it?

Answer (score 0):

what about delete?

```
delete object['property'];
```

I think that removes it completely not just assigning it to undefined.